# A UI control for Ipad to brose a list of images

Tags: uitableview, uiimage, xamarin.ios, ipad

I have made the decision to use monotouch to develop an application that browses an rss feed and displays a grid of images much like browsing the picture library actually on the device.

My issue is that I have NO idea (even after extensive googling) as to what control I should use.

I want to be able to swish through the list of images which I really wanted in a UITableView BUT all documentation insists that UITableView only has 1 column :(

I dont want to get too complicated with my requirement at this stage for unloading and loading resource as the images go off screen but if anyone has any pointers for me in starting this and what control I should go for I would be grateful.

My initial thoughts are perhaps having n images in every cell and the cells are very wide (would an ipad only display those it can and automatically allow swiping to the others off screen?)

Many thanks

Richard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UItableView is only one column, but you can define the UITableViewCell to your own class and allow any number of elements across it.

As to whether something goes off the screen, that is entirely down to your application.

Have a look at the developer videos on iTunes, especially the beginning table views sections, that should point you in the right way

Comment: thanks woody will take a look... I am actually using an rss feed to store data in sqllite db on the device and use that as my source for the images...